# merge all documents in a folder in particular order and sort the merged output

Tags: perl, sorting, merge

i am not programmer, i just install active perl.
where can i find information to do the following.

in a folder i have various txt documents, 
i want to merge the first two and sort the result in **stable** way
and save it as a new document in a subfolder called : merged.

then do the same with the following txt documents, other 2 documents.
this way until finishing with all files.

---

files on the directory look like this.

```
subtitle(english).txt
subtitle(spanish).txt
othername1(english).txt
othername1(spanish).txt
etc etc
```

they are placed, the english version and the spanish version below if are sorted alphabetically.

i need to merge the two first, then the others (2 at the time, so that it does not mix data)

after merging the two the content merged would look like this:

```
1.- <english> hi 
1.- <spanish> hola.
2.- <english> thanks
2.- <spanish> gracias
```

because the original order in every file is for example english.

```
1.- <english> hi
2.- <english> thanks
```

thanks
about the output name, could be whatever, or the same name as in english or spanish, meaning the first or second file.

Comment: When you say *"the first two"* etc. in what order is the directory to be read? Are the original files sorted before merging? Please give some examples of file names, and the name of the output file you would like. Are

Comment: they are sorted alphabetically, the two files are sorted indeed they are with line numbers: line number one has a 1 at the begging of the line, line 2 has number 2, and son on, the same with file 2.          they are translations, in one file is english and in the other one is spanish,  every line corresponds to the other document. i will details in the main post

Comment: Ah, so you really want to just *interleave* the two files?

Comment: yes, if that is how is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you but I can't test it easily.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @files = do {
  opendir my $dh, '.';
  sort grep /\.txt\z/, grep -f, readdir $dh;
};

my $re = qr/\A ( [^()]+? ) \s* \( \s* ( .+ ) \s* \) [^()]+ \z /ix;

my @badfiles = grep $_ !~ $re, @files;
if (@badfiles) {
  print STDERR "These file names do not match the expected pattern\n";
  print STDERR "  $_\n" for @badfiles;
  print STDERR "\n";
  die "Invalid input files";
}

mkdir 'merged' unless -d 'merged';

while (@files > 1) {

  my @files = splice @files, 0, 2;
  my @fh = map { open my $fh, '<', $_; $fh } @files;
  my @details = map [ $_ =~ $re ], @files;
  my $newfile = sprintf "merged/%s(%s-%s).txt",
      $details[0][0],
      $details[0][1],
      $details[1][1];

  printf "%s + %s => %s ... ", @files, $newfile;

  open my $out_fh, '>', $newfile;
  until (grep eof, @fh) {
    print $out_fh scalar readline $_ for @fh;
  }
  close $out_fh;

  print "done\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, i will try it, and i will tell you.

Comment: i save the script as merger.pl and i added it to the directory where the files are.  doble click on the pl file , since i am using active perl 5. 16 .3  but did not happen anything. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using Windows? I don't know how ActivePerl works, but that sounds right. have you run other scripts that way? Do you know how to use the command line? The problem with double-clicking a script on Windows is that the command prompt window flashes up only briefly while the program runs and you don't get a chance to read it.

Comment: Invalid input files at C:\Documents and Settings\user\Escritorio\leerme\prueba\m
erger.pl line 17. These file names do not match the expected pattern
  doc(english).txt.txt
  doc(spanish).txt.txt
  merger.pl
  subtitle(english).txt.txt
  subtitle(spanish).txt.txt    i don't know why is marking it as doble .txt.txt  since i save it as .txt , yes i am using xp, and i was running another script and it worked.

Comment: It lists the invalid files first. What does it say?

Comment: These file names do not match the expected pattern
  doc(english).txt.txt
  doc(spanish).txt.txt
  merger.pl
  subtitle(english).txt.txt
  subtitle(spanish).txt.txt

Comment: You have named your files with two suffixes `.txt.txt`. My program checks that all the files looks like you said `xxx(language).txt`.

Comment: I have changed line 7 in the program. Please copy the fix over. (You still need to correct your file names.)

Comment: hey i tried it on copies of my originals but it still continues saying : these file names do not match the expected pattern. and then it lists the files with a normal .txt extension. the names of the files could have numbers, - hyphen, parenthesis, stress marks because some spanish titles. thanks for the help , i will do , what you say, runnint it again

Comment: Okay try now. I have changed the line starting `my $re`

Comment: C:\Nueva carpeta>merger.pl
These file names do not match the expected pattern
  2 Broke Girls 1x01 - Pilot (Espa±ol (LatinoamÚrica))_modified.txt
  2 Broke Girls 1x02 - And the Break up Scene (Espa±ol (LatinoamÚrica))_modified
.txt
  2 Broke Girls 1x04 - And the Rich People Problems (Espa±ol (LatinoamÚrica))_mo
dified.txt
  2 Broke Girls 1x06 - And The Disappearing Bed (Espa±ol (LatinoamÚrica))_modifi
ed.txt

Invalid input files at C:\Nueva carpeta\merger.pl line 17.

Comment: that was using copy of the originals i want to merge.  i change the files to a c:nueva carpeta .....  but it is not working, maybe the titles is the problem, but to change more than 30 thousand is difficult.

Comment: Try again please same line changed again

Comment: Don't worry, the problem is that the file names are different from the way you told me and I can't see the directory. It may be an idea to put the list up on pastebin

Comment: omg it was like magic, it merged them all in the correct order. that was fantastic, i am so thankful, i vote up and mark as good one. god bless you

Comment: Excellent. And the output file names are OK?

Comment: hey, the first one was repeating english, other documents where good

Comment: hey my bad, the source was wrong, that is why, my sorce english and source spanish where both in english, that is why,but it is working correctly